# Receiving errors when running reports. "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment."

Tags: civireport, civicrm-home

Drupal 7.41
CiviCRM 4.6.6

We are using an older version of CiviCRM and are randomly starting to get "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment." when running certain reports.

I enabled backtrace and debugging.  Below are the results.

Any help would be appreciated.  This happens randomly but is happening more and more often now.

backTrace

#0 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 internal function: CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#4 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#5 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_705_0.MYI'; try to repair it")
#7 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#9 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#10 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#11 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#12 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1179): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...", TRUE)
#13 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(2776): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...")
#14 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Activity.php(763): CRM_Report_Form->buildRows("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARA...", (Array:0))
#15 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form.php(753): CRM_Report_Form_Activity->postProcess()
#16 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Report_Form->preProcess()
#17 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#18 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Activity), "display")
#19 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Report_Form_Activity), "display")
#20 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#21 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Page/Instance.php(101): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Report_Form_Activity", NULL, NULL)
#23 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Report_Page_Instance->run((Array:4), NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#25 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#26 /var/www/html/Dash/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#27 internal function: civicrm_invoke("report", "instance", "42")
#28 /var/www/html/Dash/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#29 /var/www/html/Dash/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: unknown error
Error Details
Database Error Code: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_705_0.MYI'; try to repair it, 126
Additional Details:
Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => handle
)

```
[code] => -1
[message] => DB Error: unknown error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_source_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_source_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, civicrm_activity_id, civicrm_activity_source_record_id, civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, civicrm_activity_activity_subject, civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, civicrm_activity_status_id, civicrm_address_state_province_id, civicrm_value_practice_profile_4_custom_22, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_3, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_5, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_7
```

FROM civireport_activity_temp_target tar
GROUP BY civicrm_activity_id  ORDER BY civicrm_activity_activity_date_time ASC, option_value_civireport ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_705_0.MYI'; try to repair it]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_source_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_source_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, civicrm_activity_id, civicrm_activity_source_record_id, civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, civicrm_activity_activity_subject, civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, civicrm_activity_status_id, civicrm_address_state_province_id, civicrm_value_practice_profile_4_custom_22, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_3, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_5, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_7
FROM civireport_activity_temp_target tar
GROUP BY civicrm_activity_id  ORDER BY civicrm_activity_activity_date_time ASC, option_value_civireport ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_705_0.MYI'; try to repair it]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_source_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_source_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_assignee_id, GROUP_CONCAT(civicrm_contact_contact_target_id SEPARATOR ';') as civicrm_contact_contact_target_id, civicrm_activity_id, civicrm_activity_source_record_id, civicrm_activity_activity_type_id, civicrm_activity_activity_subject, civicrm_activity_activity_date_time, civicrm_activity_status_id, civicrm_address_state_province_id, civicrm_value_practice_profile_4_custom_22, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_3, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_5, civicrm_value_activity_wrap_up_1_custom_7
FROM civireport_activity_temp_target tar
GROUP BY civicrm_activity_id  ORDER BY civicrm_activity_activity_date_time ASC, option_value_civireport ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=126 ** Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_705_0.MYI'; try to repair it]"]
)
Return to home page.

Answer (score 1):

Just a directory filling up.  Deleted some unused files and the error went away.